# Dcu file not found

Tags: delphi, file-not-found, dcu

i have a problem compiling my Delphi code.
I have 3 classes, XmlFileManager (concrete), XmlNodeManager (abstract), XmlEnpManager (child of XmlNodeManager and concrete).
Below, a little of definition class code:

**XmlFileManager**

```
unit XmlFileManager;
interface
uses
  xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, SysUtils, DateUtils, Classes, Dialogs,
  XmlNodeManager, XmlEnpManager;
type
  TXmlFileManager = class
     [...]
  end;
[...]
end.
```

**XmlNodeManager**

```
unit XmlNodeManager;
interface
uses
  xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, SysUtils, DateUtils, Classes, Dialogs,
  XmlFileManager;
type
  TXmlNodeManager = class
     [...]
  end;
[...]
end.
```

**XmlEnpManager**

```
unit XmlEnpManager;

interface
uses
  xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, SysUtils, DateUtils, Classes, Dialogs,
  XmlFileManager,  XmlNodeManager;

type
  TXmlEnpManager = class (TXmlNodeManager)
      [...]
  end;
[...]
end.
```

In the XmlNodeManager and XmlEnpManager, not recognize TXmlFileManager class. An whe i compile, the compilation fails with message:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] SiGAS.dpr(23): F1026 File not found:
>   'XmlManager.dcu'

In the past, the XmlFileManager was called XmlManager.
Any ideas ?.

My .dpr:

```
uses
  Forms,
  Main in 'forms\Main.pas' {Principal},
  Globals in 'units\Globals.pas',
  CrearProyectoForm in 'forms\CrearProyectoForm.pas' {NuevoProyecto},
  Validadores in 'units\Validadores.pas',
  IdiomaClass in 'units\IdiomaClass.pas',
  IdiomaCastellanoClass in 'units\IdiomaCastellanoClass.pas',
  ExcelFileManagerClass in 'units\ExcelFileManagerClass.pas',
  SeleccionarIdioma in 'forms\SeleccionarIdioma.pas' {SelectLang},
  EnpView in 'forms\EnpView.pas' {ENP},
  EnpViewGeneric in 'forms\EnpViewGeneric.pas' {EnpGeneric},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles,
  EnpViewAdd in 'forms\EnpViewAdd.pas' {EnpAdd},
  EnpViewAddAfter in 'forms\EnpViewAddAfter.pas' {EnpAddAfter},
  EnpViewEdit in 'forms\EnpViewEdit.pas' {EnpEdit},
  EnpInicial in 'forms\EnpInicial.pas' {ENPViewInicial},
  XmlFileManager in 'units\XmlFileManager.pas',
  XmlNodeManager in 'units\XmlNodeManager.pas',
  XmlEnpManager in 'units\XmlEnpManager.pas';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your main source file, `SiGAS.dpr`, still has it listed as XmlManager, so...

**Open your *.dpr file (it is just Delphi code) and fix the unit name in the `uses` clause, then rebuild.**

Comment: Open your `*.dpr` file,it is just a Delphi code, and fix the unit name in  the `uses` close.

Comment: +1, but it would be better if you edited your answer and provided the info on how to fix it there, instead of burying it in the comments.

Comment: @eugener thanks for reply, again. I edit the post with the .dpr "uses" content. All files, are ok. I dont have "XmlManager" anymore, why the message persist ?.

Comment: is message exactly the same? did you do full rebuild?

Comment: Rebuild from project -> build, and the problem disappeared. But, now, have problem of circular unit reference xD. But, is topic for other post.

Comment: Good to hear! There is only one way to solve circular unit ref - move all the units you don't need from interface sections to implementation sections